# AWS Data Pipeline is not creating all slave / core instance nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I have tried creating AWS Data pipelines using the CLI and also using the GUI.  Either way, when I specify more than one slave node, it doesn't get created properly.  Here is an example definition:

```
{
    "name": "EmrClusterForLoad",
    "coreInstanceCount": "16",
    "coreInstanceType": "r3.xlarge",
    "releaseLabel": "emr-5.13.0",
    "id": "EmrClusterForLoad",
    "masterInstanceType": "r3.xlarge",
    "region": "#{myDDBRegion}",
    "type": "EmrCluster"
},
```

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what error you are encountering, when you say its doesn't get created properly ?

Comment: Wish I could.  When I go to EC2 dashboard, there is only 1 instance created.  When I go to EMR/Hardware, it only lists one instance.  I am not seeing any errors - maybe I am looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird.  I think this may be a bug.  The "fix" was to change the value of the "Resize Cluster Before Running:" from true to false.  If it's not a bug, then I am not sure I understand the option.

If you are creating the pipeline via CLI, then the entry is:

```
"resizeClusterBeforeRunning": "false"
```

When I changed this value, all of the sudden the EC2 instances started to be created.

Comment: Good catch, as per documentation it does overrides your instance type. It doesn't state clearly but maybe it does override the count parameter as well to default unless you set corresponding resize count parameter `resizeClusterMaxInstances`. And by default, this parameter should be false, unless you override to true with specific use case.

Comment: Yeah - When I create a custom one, I generally create from template and then cut and paste the definition as my starting point.  I went back and looked at a bunch of my templates and they all have it set to true.  Not sure why we would ever want it set to true.  From what I see, true == ignore all resource settings.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of, if you are exhausting your account's EC2 resource [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html). Datapipeline [honors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-limits.html#dp-limits-account) this limit.

If you are not exhausting limit, then go to AWS console for [EMR](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/home), find the corresponding booted cluster >> Debug >> check logs for steps, see if something stands out.

 You can also launch a EMR cluster directly from console, and see if you can spin up more than 1 slave core nodes.
Other than that configuration wise you look good, I would recommend reaching out to AWS support for further debugging.